# Yii ::: CGridView ::: dataprovider is not working / class is not passing data

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I am trying to pass data from another model to my view page with CGridView and  controller. It is showing some error:

```
urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I created a function for dataProvider.

##### controller

```
        public function actionClassA()
    {
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Codesparam', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'condition'=>'cm_type="Branch"',
        ),
    ));
     $this->render('admina', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
   }
```

##### view

```
      $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'id'=>'productmaster-grid',
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  //'filter'=>$result,
  ));
```

Comment: There are no errors in this code. May be you have the error in some other statements

Comment: please show the code where you have used  **urlencode()**

Comment: @Hearaman-హేరామన్ you are right.

Comment: @Letmesee I didn't use anywhere **urlencode()**

Comment: the post the full script

Comment: Here is the full post I think... I got the issue. There is the main issue for composite primarykey. Trying to solve them

Comment: Can you replace 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, with this, $model = new Codesparam(); 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),

Comment: No Actually I couldn't because this comes from another model. I got the solutions. It was an error for composite primary key. I solved it by using CButtonColumn and assign them both composite key. **I have updated my code .....**

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find your solution in the revision history and post it as an answer of its own.